# VB.NET | Array of pictureboxes in panel: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: arrays, vb.net, picturebox

In the code below I am attempting to change the tag of an existing control that was created in the array 'pictureboxes(9, 9)'. When I try to do this, I get the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. This is done in the **checkdata** sub, near the bottom of the code with the comment '***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***'.

The string that is passed through to the sub is a long string of numbers, and the pictureboxes are placed into a layoutpanel if that is helpful.

I understand what this error means, I am aware that pictureboxes(i, j) is = nothing when breakpointed; I just don't know how to fix it :s

Any help is greatly appreciated and hopefully I will be quick to answer any comments/answers.

Thank you

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
'0 as default tile, 1 as clicked, 3 as set mine (host perspective)
Dim tiles() As Integer = {0}
Public pictureboxes(9, 9) As PictureBox
Dim flagged() As Integer
Dim clicked As Integer()
Dim columns As Integer = 10
Dim rows As Integer = 10
Dim placedMinesCount As Integer = 0
Dim formattedTag As String()
Public turn As Boolean = False
Dim stringToSend As String

Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i As Byte = 0 To 9
        For j As Byte = 0 To 9

            pictureboxes(i, j) = New PictureBox
            pictureboxes(i, j).Height = 60
            pictureboxes(i, j).Width = 60
            pictureboxes(i, j).ImageLocation = "0.png"
            pictureboxes(i, j).Tag = "0|" & i & ", " & j

            AddHandler pictureboxes(i, j).Click, AddressOf Tile_Click

            Dim column As Integer = j
            Dim row As Integer = i

            Panel.Controls.Add(pictureboxes(i, j), column, row)

        Next
    Next

    If Login.isHost = True Then
        Me.Text = "Set your mines (10)"
        turn = True
    ElseIf Login.isHost = False Then
        Me.Text = "Await your turn"
        btnEndTurn.Visible = False
        btnEndTurn.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Tile_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    formatSenderTag(sender.tag)
    If Login.isHost = True Then
        Dim clickAction As String = formattedTag(0)

        Select Case clickAction
            Case "0"
                If placedMinesCount < 10 Then
                    placedMinesCount = placedMinesCount + 1
                    sender.imagelocation = "3.png"
                    sender.tag = "3"
                    Me.Text = "Set your mines (" & 10 - placedMinesCount & ")"

                ElseIf placedMinesCount >= 10 Then
                    MsgBox("You have placed all of your 10 Mines")
                End If
            Case "2"
                MsgBox("You cannot set a mine here")
            Case "3"
                placedMinesCount = placedMinesCount - 1
                Me.Text = "Set your mines (" & 10 - placedMinesCount & ")"
                sender.imagelocation = "0.png"
                sender.tag = "0"
        End Select


    ElseIf Login.isHost = False Then
        Dim clickAction As String = formattedTag(0)
        Select Case clickAction
            Case "0"
                sender.tag = "1"
                sender.imagelocation = "1.png"
            Case "3"
                MsgBox("Game Over")
            Case "2"
                MsgBox("Already Clicked")
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub formatSenderTag(ByVal sender As String)
    'split into array 
    'element 0 as TILE TYPE
    'element 1 as TILE LOCATION
    formattedTag = sender.Split(New String() {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    End
End Sub

Private Sub btnEndTurn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEndTurn.Click
    turn = False

    gridtostring()
    senddata()
End Sub

Private Sub gridtostring()
    For i As Byte = 0 To 9
        For j As Byte = 0 To 9
            formatSenderTag(pictureboxes(i, j).Tag & "|")
            stringToSend = stringToSend & formattedTag(0)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub senddata()
    '***SEND STUFF
    'Assuming you have a textbox with the data you want to send
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToSend)) Then
        Dim data() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToSend)
        Login.sendingClient.Send(data, data.Length)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub checkdata(ByVal data As String)
    If Not data = stringToSend Then
        'Dim loopcount As Integer = 0
        For i As Byte = 0 To 9
            For j As Byte = 0 To 9
                Dim loopcount As Integer = (i.ToString & j.ToString) + 1
                'Dim pineapple As String = pictureboxes(i, j).Tag
                'pictureboxes(i, j).Tag = GetChar(data, 3)

                pictureboxes(i, j).Tag = GetChar(data, loopcount) & "|" & i & ", " & j '***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***
                formatSenderTag(pictureboxes(i, j).Tag)
                pictureboxes(i, j).ImageLocation = formattedTag(0)
                pictureboxes(i, j).ImageLocation = "0.png"
                'Panel.Controls(pictureboxes(i, j).Tag) = GetChar(data, 3) '.Tag = GetChar(data, 3)

            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

***AND BELOW IS THE OTHER FORM WHICH CALLS CHECKDATA()

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net

Public Class Login

Dim Port As Integer = 8123
Private Const broadcastAddress As String = "255.255.255.255"
Public receivingClient As UdpClient
Public sendingClient As UdpClient
Dim sendAddress As String
Dim ServerMode As Boolean = False
Public isHost As Boolean = true
Dim returndata As String

Private Sub Login_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub ComboWANLAN_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboWANLAN.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboWANLAN.Text = "Online (WAN)" Then
        txtSendAddress.Enabled = True
    ElseIf ComboWANLAN.Text = "Offline (LAN)" Then
        txtSendAddress.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnConnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
    '***START PORT LISTENING/SENDING AND NETWORKING STUFFS
    Port = txtPort.Text
    InitializeSender()
    InitializeReceiver()

End Sub

Private Sub btnHost_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHost.Click
    '***START PORT LISTENING/SENDING AND NETWORKING STUFFS
    Port = txtPort.Text
    InitializeSender()
    InitializeReceiver()
    isHost = True
    Me.Hide()
    Form1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeSender()
    If ComboWANLAN.Text = "Offline (LAN)" Then
        sendingClient = New UdpClient(broadcastAddress, Port)
        'Use broadcastAddress for sending data locally (on LAN), otherwise you'll need the public (or global) IP address of the machine that you want to send your data to
    ElseIf ComboWANLAN.Text = "Online (WAN)" Then
        sendAddress = txtSendAddress.Text
        sendingClient = New UdpClient(sendAddress, Port)
        'Use broadcastAddress for sending data locally (on LAN), otherwise you'll need the public (or global) IP address of the machine that you want to send your data to
    End If
    sendingClient.EnableBroadcast = True
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeReceiver()
    receivingClient = New UdpClient(Port)
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf Receiver) 'Start listener on another thread
End Sub

Private Sub Receiver()
    Dim endPoint As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port) 'Listen for incoming data from any IP on the specified port
    Do While True 'Notice that i've setup an infinite loop to continually listen for incoming data
        Dim data() As Byte
        data = receivingClient.Receive(endPoint)
        If Form1.turn = False Then
            returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data) 'Recived data as string
            Form1.checkdata(returndata)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Form_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    End
End Sub
End Class
```

***STACK TRACE

```
   at Minesweeper.Form1.checkdata(String data) in                c:\users\harry\documents\visual studio     2010\Projects\Minesweeper\Minesweeper\Form1.vb:line 139
   at Minesweeper.Login.Receiver() in C:\Users\Harry\Documents\Visual Studio     2010\Projects\Minesweeper\Minesweeper\Login.vb:line 71
   at Minesweeper.Login._Lambda$__1(Object a0) in C:\Users\Harry\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Minesweeper\Minesweeper\Login.vb:line 61
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Note: Screwed up with the spacings in some places

Comment: Per the trace it looks like that the login receiver sends the call. Where do you instantiate Form1 in your login class? You need to add:   Dim Form1 as New Form1

Comment: Haha, yeah, that seems to of done it. Could you make this comment an answer so that I can mark it as the final answer please?

Thanks :D.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear! I updated the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36951237/6201755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not give an error with the data you gave:

```
checkdata("00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000‌​00000000000000000000")

Public Sub checkdata(ByVal data As String)
    If Not data = stringToSend Then
        'Dim loopcount As Integer = 0
        For i As Byte = 0 To 9
            For j As Byte = 0 To 9
                Dim loopcount As Integer = (i.ToString & j.ToString) + 1
                'Dim pineapple As String = pictureboxes(i, j).Tag
                'pictureboxes(i, j).Tag = GetChar(data, 3)

                pictureboxes(i, j).Tag = GetChar(data, loopcount) & "|" & i & ", " & j '***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***
                formatSenderTag(pictureboxes(i, j).Tag)
                pictureboxes(i, j).ImageLocation = formattedTag(0)
                pictureboxes(i, j).ImageLocation = "0.png"
                'Panel.Controls(pictureboxes(i, j).Tag) = GetChar(data, 3) '.Tag = GetChar(data, 3)

            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Looking at your stack trace and code, you are missing the instantiation of Form1 in your login class. I think this can be the problem.

Try adding this to the beginning of your Login class:

```
Dim Form1 as New Form1
```

Comment: But it throws the error when it runs the at pictureboxes(0, 0) and I definitely have 0, 0 as an existing thing. If I hardcode the numbers and remove the variables from that line, it does the same thing.

Comment: What is the value of the `data` and the `loopcount` at that line? Also, your code sample does not include the call to the `Sub checkdata`. Can you also post this?

Comment: Where is Stack trace for this exception? If you analyse it then it will clearly give you a line where it throws exception. You will haveto study the trace path carefully. Provide the trace so that amswer can be given

Comment: The Value of data is: 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The value of Loopcount is: 1

(The value for data is correct, because they are all the defaults in the application because I haven't changed anything for testing)

The idea was that it would choose the first number from data, assign it as the tag for the first thing in the pictureboxes array, then so and so with the second, etc

Comment: Thanks. See the code update above. It does not give an object reference error. So you need to look deeper. What is the stack trace as Mukesh asked. Nothing is wrong with that. The error you get is what it says, literally. You try to access an object that does not exist. Can you paste your actual code?

Comment: Sorry - wasn't exactly sure what a stack trace was (Never actually heard of it before because I haven't being doing this for that long)

Hope this is what you were looking for:    

    
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    


Error in ClaimFlag10 - Line number:134

Comment: When you get the error, on the bottom of the box there is View detail... If you open that that has a "Stack Trace" entry. that tells you line by line what calls were made before the error. The latest is on top.

Comment: Editted original post